# Will I have enough time for my connection in Schiphol Airport?

Tags: schengen, airport-security, short-connections, connecting-flights, ams

I am flying from Germany to the USA with a 1 hour and 50 minute layover in Amsterdam Schipol Airport later this month (December 20th).

I know I need to go through some extra security when I arrive in Amsterdam in order to travel to the USA. so will a 1 hour and 50 minute connection be enough time?

Comment: Did you book separate tickets or are both connections in a ticket only? The answer may depend on that.

Comment: @nsn I booked the flights all together. So, not seperately. I am flying to Amsterdam with KLM and then to the States with Delta.